# Angular $watch with array splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, watch, splice

I've got a problem regarding watcher in Angular and array splice. Combined both of them have a really strange behaviour. So i created a small demo with logs showing the problem that's happening. Here is the code I'm having or you can see it working in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4PzBRF9khwkBRjhvbcdz?p=preview).

**html:**

```
<div class="logs">
    <div><b>LOGS:</b></div>
    <ul ng-repeat="watchEntry in watchersLogs track by $index">
      <li>{{watchEntry}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div><b>Watcher Count:</b> {{watchers.length}}</div>
</div>
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in list" ng-init="InitItem()">
  <div class="item-title-wrapper">
    <span class="item-title">Item {{ $index + 1 }}</span>
    <button ng-click="AddNewItem()">Add New</button>
    <button ng-click="RemoveItem()">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div>
      CREDIT:
      <input type="number" name="credit" ng-model="item.credit" />
    </div>
    <div>
      DEBIT:
      <input type="number" name="debit" ng-model="item.debit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var app = angular.module("listApp", []);
app.controller("listController", function($scope) {
  // list with all data:
  $scope.list = [{
    credit: 2000,
    debit: 0
  }, {
    credit: 100000,
    debit: 1000
  }];

  // list containing all watchers:
  $scope.watchers = [];
  // logs containing all watcher event:
  $scope.watchersLogs = [];

  function SetWatcher(itemIndex) {
    $scope.watchers.splice(itemIndex, 0, $scope.$watch("list[" + itemIndex + "]", function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
      $scope.watchersLogs.push("Item " + itemIndex + " watcher fired!");
    }, true));
  }

  $scope.InitItem = function() {
    // set a watcher for newly create item:
    SetWatcher(this.$index);
  }

  $scope.AddNewItem = function() {
    var newItem = {
      credit: 0,
      debit: 0
    };

    // put the item into the array:
    $scope.list.splice((this.$index + 1), 0, newItem);
  };

  $scope.RemoveItem = function() {
    // destroy the watcher:
    $scope.watchers[this.$index]();
    $scope.watchers.splice(this.$index, 1);
    // remove the item from the list:
    $scope.list.splice(this.$index, 1);
  };
});
```

**css:**

```
.logs {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

So, as you can see there, when I'm initializing or adding a new item into the `$scope.list` array, I'm assigning to it a new watcher. From the logs you can see that each watcher is fired at start-up only once which is fine. However, my application needs the item to be added after the one you selected or currently reviewing /e.g. if you have 3 items and click the **Add New** button for the 2nd one, it should add a new entry on 3rd place/. That's why I'm using `splice`.

However, this is causing `$watch` expression to be executed multiple times sometimes. So, if you add a new entry in the last place it will fire the `$watch` expression only once for it. That's okay. But, if you add it somewhere in the middle /e.g. 2nd, 3rd, etc./, the watcher expression is going to be fired not only for it, but for all other items that are after it as well. I'm guessing that `splice` somehow changes the reference of the items after the newly created one, that's why the `$watch` is executed when that happens.

I need the `$watch` expressions as I'm doing some calculations when values are being changed, so I think I can't get rid of them. I need the `splice` functionality too, as I mentioned before... So, any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

**...UPDATE...**

I resolved the problem! Big thanks to @Deblaton Jean-Philippe for the help. SO, first of all I created a new function for removing the watchers:

```
function RemoveWatcher(itemIndex) {
  if ($scope.watchers[itemIndex]) {
    // destroy the watcher:
    $scope.watchers[itemIndex]();
    // remove it from the array as well:
    $scope.watchers.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

I'm calling it before setting up a new watcher in order to be sure that it's cleared. I;m calling it inside the `RemoveItem` method as well, but the tricky thing here is that I'm always removing the last watcher entry from the array, as I'm splicing the `$scope.list` array and it changes the order of the fields. SO what I'm doing there is just calling the `RemoveWatcher` method like so:

```
RemoveWatcher($scope.watchers.length - 1);
```

This seems to be working perfectly! You can check the updated Plunker as well. :)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if the site went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.) Also, some people are behind corporate firewalls that forbid the use of code sharing websites.

Comment: Done! :) I updated my question with the code and added the resolution as well. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing what you've asked him to do. He is watching the value at the index you've asked.

If you add a new watch on and index already registered, it will be triggered twice.

If you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), you will see that **`$watch()` returns a function. Executing this function will unregister your watch.**

What you need to do is, when you add a new item, is unregistering the watch that is there.

Maybe something like this could help you :

```
  function SetWatcher(itemIndex) {
    if($scope.watchers[itemIndex]) $scope.watchers[itemIndex]();
    $scope.watchers.splice(itemIndex, 0, $scope.$watch("list[" + itemIndex + "]", function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
      $scope.watchersLogs.push("Item " + itemIndex + " watcher fired!");
    }, true));
  }
```

Comment: You're totally right there! Applying that simple check when setting the watcher is fixing the problem. Thanks a lot for your help! :))

Comment: I don't think this code is enough. If you add something in the middle of the array, I'm pretty sure the last item of your array won't trigger a single watch. I suggest you to always add items at the end of your array, and order your view with a filter (|).

Comment: Actually, what I did is to add new items using `splice`, but when I remove them from the button, I always remove the last watcher from the array. I seemed to work out perfectly. Check the updated **Plunker** :)